# pyodbc: ('Params must be in a list, tuple, or Row', 'HY000') with NumPy data

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pyodbc

I am trying to insert a list of tuples into an MS SQL table via pyodbc with Python 3. This works:

```
conn_string = (('DRIVER=FreeTDS;'
                'SERVER={};'
                'PORT=1433;'
                'DATABASE={};'
                'UID={};'
                'PWD={};'
                'TDS_Version=8.0;')
               .format(server, db, user, pwd))
sql = """
insert into Table1(field1, field2, field3) values (?, ?, ?)
"""

cursor.executemany(sql, [('1175B57E-7A10-4BAC-B22E-457C8266C0F2', '1D111FA5-A65D-4F77-A3AB-78B80BAF0C0B', 2),
 ('C60FA1C9-7656-4EBF-A577-44CBF0C641F4', '365FB706-9F7F-4ED4-AB88-927AE1F762A6', 1),
 ('2DF071CE-ABDF-4119-9573-2B0CA2B99C9C', '590E266D-810C-4DC2-BA5A-BAC05A9982C4', 0),
 ('EB794EF9-5FF4-49D3-B81E-F14F69C09306', '1D6E0C95-DF96-45D5-B8F3-211D825A160F', 0),
 ('EB794EF9-5FF4-49D3-B81E-F14F69C09306', '17D2EC66-845F-495D-9020-91E144B2E595', 0),
 ('EB794EF9-5FF4-49D3-B81E-F14F69C09306', '3A694B33-39F4-4F5B-899B-9B27810E4D82', 1),
 ('2DF071CE-ABDF-4119-9573-2B0CA2B99C9C', '4EE1D6F4-4A1E-4316-93D5-2AE1F461A193', 0),
 ('410DE087-1ADF-4EEA-BCE6-D7A1124E2A51', '17D2EC66-845F-495D-9020-91E144B2E595', 0),
 ('C60FA1C9-7656-4EBF-A577-44CBF0C641F4', '250256D4-4A3A-48E0-BCBA-7CD89011D81F', 1),
 ('2DF071CE-ABDF-4119-9573-2B0CA2B99C9C', '4D363718-FE0C-4257-8E4C-5C9A024BAEFF', 0)])
```

but this does not:

```
params = list(row for row in data_table.round(0).head(10).to_records(index=False))

cursor.executemany(sql, params)
```

producing this error:

```
('Params must be in a list, tuple, or Row', 'HY000')
```

even though the output of `params` is:

```
[('1175B57E-7A10-4BAC-B22E-457C8266C0F2', '1D111FA5-A65D-4F77-A3AB-78B80BAF0C0B', 2),
     ('C60FA1C9-7656-4EBF-A577-44CBF0C641F4', '365FB706-9F7F-4ED4-AB88-927AE1F762A6', 1),
     ('2DF071CE-ABDF-4119-9573-2B0CA2B99C9C', '590E266D-810C-4DC2-BA5A-BAC05A9982C4', 0),
     ('EB794EF9-5FF4-49D3-B81E-F14F69C09306', '1D6E0C95-DF96-45D5-B8F3-211D825A160F', 0),
     ('EB794EF9-5FF4-49D3-B81E-F14F69C09306', '17D2EC66-845F-495D-9020-91E144B2E595', 0),
     ('EB794EF9-5FF4-49D3-B81E-F14F69C09306', '3A694B33-39F4-4F5B-899B-9B27810E4D82', 1),
     ('2DF071CE-ABDF-4119-9573-2B0CA2B99C9C', '4EE1D6F4-4A1E-4316-93D5-2AE1F461A193', 0),
     ('410DE087-1ADF-4EEA-BCE6-D7A1124E2A51', '17D2EC66-845F-495D-9020-91E144B2E595', 0),
     ('C60FA1C9-7656-4EBF-A577-44CBF0C641F4', '250256D4-4A3A-48E0-BCBA-7CD89011D81F', 1),
     ('2DF071CE-ABDF-4119-9573-2B0CA2B99C9C', '4D363718-FE0C-4257-8E4C-5C9A024BAEFF', 0)]
```

Comment: Just tested, I cannot recreate your issue. What is your RDMS?

Comment: Thanks. It is MS SQL Server 2014. The string fields are COLLATE "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" if that helps.

Comment: What you have in params is a list, and a list cannot be passed as a function argument. Try changing it as `params = (('A', 'B', 2),('C', 'D', 1),('E', 'F', 0))` and let me know

Comment: I think I figured it out - `to_records()` actually creates a list of numpy.records. I changed that up to be `params = list(tuple(row) for row in data_table.head(10).values)` and it works.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As stated in the comments to the question, the issue was that

```python
cursor.executemany(sql, params)
```

was failing because

```python
params = list(row for row in data_table.round(0).head(10).to_records(index=False))
```

was not returning a list of "list[s], tuple[s], or [pyodbc] Row[s]", it was returning a list of "numpy.records". The solution was to convert the "records" so that `params` contained a list of tuples:

```python
params = list(tuple(row) for row in data_table.head(10).values)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it is important to point out that if you use `tuple(__item__)`, your strings will be seperated by every char ... think of your string as a C++ const char pointer. The tuple is taking that item of const chars pointers and putting all the elemetns into a tuple. To stop this you can put your string in a list as so: `tuple([__string__])`. The list will not stay in the tuple it is just saying put this WHOLE item of const char pointers as one element into my tuple. Hope this was helpful, recently had this problem at work.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to contribute an answer. Please consider reading question carefully. What your have answered is not what OP is looking for. Don't put references from other programming languages. There might be a chance that the one who looking for this answer doesn't know that language.