# Execute many issue CSV to Microsoft SQL Server in Python

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x

I am trying to insert 2,000,000 records from a `.CSV` file into Microsoft SQL Server using Python. Standard insert function took me 3 hours to upload all records. I am trying to reduce this to minutes.

I am fairly new to Python.

```
import pyodbc
import csv
import time
import pandas as pd

new_data = []
t0 = time.time()

conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                      'Server=xyz;'
                      'Database=Rst;'
                      'Trusted_Connection=yes;')

cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.fast_executemany = True

parameter = [()]

with open(r"\\abc.csv") as csvDataFile:
    csvReader = csv.reader(csvDataFile)
    next(csvReader)

    for row in csvReader:
        cursor.executemany('INSERT INTO [dbo].[Science_Catalogue_Extraction]([Supplier],[Catalogue_Number],[Description],[Long_Description],[UNSPSC_Code],[CAS_Number],[Victoria_Hazard_Flag],[Overall_Status],[Chemical_Buyers_Override],[Standard_Buyers_Override])''VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)',row)

print(f'{time.time() - t0:.1f} seconds')    
conn.commit()
cursor.close()
conn.close()`
```

I am getting an error

> TypeError: ('Params must be in a list, tuple, or Row', 'HY000').

Please help :(

Comment: the error should tell you what the issue is, why don’t you print out the row and see what it looks like

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pyodbc: ('Params must be in a list, tuple, or Row', 'HY000') with NumPy data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42286679/pyodbc-params-must-be-in-a-list-tuple-or-row-hy000-with-numpy-data)

Comment: Cheers for the help. Now i am getting memory error.

Comment: @Shiv Chandra- try below approach and let me know if it works faster https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46684359/speed-up-insert-to-sql-server-from-csv-file-without-using-bulk-insert-or-pandas

Comment: below is one more approach loading huge csv file using powershell. I haven't tested it.. https://blog.netnerds.net/2015/01/powershell-high-performance-techniques-for-importing-csv-to-sql-server/

Comment: Let me know which one works faster